# CloudKit locations closest to point

Tags: ios, nspredicate, core-location, cloudkit

I'm looking for a query for CloudKit that could return me objects with locations closest to mine, sorted by the distance. For now I can get locations within certain distance from my point.

```
NSPredicate(format: "distanceToLocation:fromLocation:(%K,%@) < %f","Location",location,radiusInKilometers)
```

But It's not what I need. What I'm looking for are locations sorted from the closest one, for me the radius doesn't matter, so solution to use this query and then sort results on my device is not good for me. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [CKLocationSortDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKLocationSortDescriptor_class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)CKLocationSortDescriptor) in your sortDescriptors and combine that with [resultsLimit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQueryOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CKQueryOperation/resultsLimit). That will let you sort by location closest to the point you provide and get a specific number of results (e.g. 5).

```
queryOperation.sortDescriptors = [CKLocationSortDescriptor(key: "location", relativeLocation: location)]
queryOperation.resultsLimit = 5
```